# Creating Custom Flask WTForms Widgets

Tags: python, forms, flask, widget, wtforms

I have a custom Flask `WTForm` where I want to have a portion of that form that includes a list of button type inputs that are created based on the number of entries in a table but have been having difficulties having them show up the way I want and passing the form validation. My goal for the look of this field is to have it show up as an [Inline Button Group with a Checkbox type input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xlnk.png). Below is an example of my route method.

```py
@bp.route('/new_channel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_channel():

    # Pre-populate the NewChannelForm 
    newChannelForm = NewChannelForm()
    newChannelForm.required_test_equipment.choices =  [(equip.id, equip.name) for equip in TestEquipmentType.query.order_by('name')]
    test_equipment_types = TestEquipmentType.query.all()

return render_template('new_channel.html', title='Add New Channel', form=newChannelForm,
                            test_equipment_types=test_equipment_types)
```

I have tried using a `FieldList` with a `FormField` containing a custom form with a `BooleanField` and managed to get the styling right but the form validation didn't work. From looking into it further, `BooleanField` isn't compatible with a `FieldList`.

My next step is to use Flask `WTForm` example of a `MultiSelectField` with a custom widget for the Field and a custom widget for the option. The default is shown below:

```py
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    """
    A multiple-select, except displays a list of checkboxes.

    Iterating the field will produce subfields, allowing custom rendering of
    the enclosed checkbox fields.
    """
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

My goal is to modify this to make a custom widget called `InLineButtonGroupWidget` which will use the styling for a list of in-line buttons like my picture included before. Additionally, I am looking to create a custom `option_widget` called `CheckboxButtonInput` to get the styling of each individual button where I can pass info to the field. This is what I have as the goal for the both:

**InLineButtonGroupWidget**:

```py
<div class="btn-group-toggle" role="group" data-toggle="buttons"></div>
```

**CheckboxButtonInput**:

```py
<label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="check-1">Calibrator
     <input type="checkbox" id="check-1">
</label>
```

The documentation for how to create custom widgets is a bit over my head and doesn't explain it the best so I'm looking for some

**Edit:**
Used Andrew Clark's suggestions and here is my final implementation:

routes.py

```py
@bp.route('/new_channel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_channel():

    class NewChannelForm(FlaskForm):
        pass
    
    test_equipment_types = TestEquipmentType.query.all()
    for test_equipment_type in test_equipment_types:
        # Create field(s) for each query result
        setattr(NewChannelForm, f'checkbox_{test_equipment_type.name}', BooleanField(label=test_equipment_type.name, id=f'checkbox-{test_equipment_type.id}'))

    newChannelForm = NewChannelForm()

    if newChannelForm.validate_on_submit():
        print('Form has been validated')

        for test_equipment_type in test_equipment_types:
            if newChannelForm.data[f'checkbox_{test_equipment_type.name}']:
                channel.add_test_equipment_type(test_equipment_type)
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))    

    print(newChannelForm.errors.items())

    return render_template('new_channel.html', title='Add New Channel', form=newChannelForm, units_dict=ENG_UNITS,
                            test_equipment_types=test_equipment_types)
```

new_channel.html

```py
    <!-- Test Equipment Selection -->
        <div class="row">  
            <legend>Test Equipment Selection:</legend>           
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn-group-toggle mb-3" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    {% for test_equipment_type in test_equipment_types %}
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="checkbox-{{ test_equipment_type.id }}">
                        {{ test_equipment_type.name }}
                        {{ form['checkbox_{}'.format(test_equipment_type.name)] }}
                    </label>                    
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: will you elaborate on this part ->  "I have a portion of that form that includes some checkbox type inputs that are created based on the number of entries in a table (~5-10)" You want the same 3 buttons showed in your screenshot, 5 to 10 times, based on a given value? Or there are many different buttons, and if value == 5,  you'll always include these 5 buttons, if value is 6, you'll provide the same 5 plus an additional one?

Comment: I've edited my post to include some code in my routes method. What I meant was that I query a table which returns a number of items, which when filled, should only be about 5-10 item. I'll use the id an name for each TestEquipmentType to populate the id for the label and input fields, as well as use the name for the text of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually tackle form building doing something like this:

```
def buildNewChannelForm():
    class NewChannelForm(FlaskForm):
        # put any non dynamic fields here
        pass

    test_equipment_types = TestEquipmentType.query.all()
    for test_equipment_object in test_equipment_types:
        # create field(s) for each query result
        setattr(NewChannelForm, f'field_name_{test_equipment_object.id}', SelectField(label='label name', choices=[(equip.id, equip.name) for equip in TestEquipmentType.query.order_by('name')]))

    return NewChannelForm()
```

## Edit 1:

## I'm not sure if there are better ways to do it, but I usually do something like this to handle data submission

```
def buildNewChannelForm():
    new_channel_form_variable_list = []
    class NewChannelForm(FlaskForm):
        # put any non dynamic fields here
        pass

    test_equipment_types = TestEquipmentType.query.all()
    for test_equipment_object in test_equipment_types:
        # create field(s) for each query result
        setattr(NewChannelForm, f'field_name_{test_equipment_object.id}', SelectField(label='label name', choices=[(equip.id, equip.name) for equip in TestEquipmentType.query.order_by('name')]))

        # append variable name
        new_channel_form_variable_list.append(f'field_name_{test_equipment_object.id}')

    return NewChannelForm(), new_channel_form_variable_list
```

## Then you can render your form using your variable list, just include in your render_template statement

```
{% for variable_name in new_channel_form_variable_list %}
    {{ form[variable_name] }}
{% endfor %}
```

## Then on submission of form in route, it's just a dictionary. So you can do something like this

```
result_dictionary = form.data

# either loop through your variable list or handle each one individually
for variable_name in new_channel_form_variable_list:
    print(f'variable name: {variable_name}, value: {result_dictionary[variable_name]}')
```

Comment: The dynamic fieldname implementation is just a suggestion. I'd recommend doing something to make it distinct.

Comment: So this adds new fields to the form and then you can specify their location/formatting in the template file? Also how would you recommend extracting the data from the new fields after it's passed form.validate_on_submit?